# IIS Express images not showing - •system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true

Tags: asp.net, iis, express

I'm using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2013. We have a virtual folder for the images we share across all applications:

```
    <application path="/WebApp" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/Image" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Image" />
    </application>
```

The images are not showing, instead, getting the following error when trying to view them:

HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Most likely causes:
•system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Things you can try:
•If the application supports it, disable client impersonation.
•If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error, it can be disabled by setting system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false.

Detailed Error Information:

Requested URL
`http://localhost.:80/image/img.png`

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Image\img.png

This works well in IIS when setting-up Image as a virtual directory under WebApp.

Thanks

Comment: FYI...ignore the localhost. (dot) ... couldn't figure out how to post this without this dot